# What happens in the end of "The Mound" by H.P. Lovecraft?

Tags: h-p-lovecraft

So the main character went inside the mound, how did he leave the mound untouched by the old beings living there? Did the tulu-metal protect him from the beings that could grab him into the mound or had the beings simply gotten weaker and weaker as time went by and died out?

Comment: What do you mean by the main character of "The Mound"?  Do you mean the 20th century narrator of the frame story, or do you mean Panfilio de Zamacona y Nunez, the Spanish explorer who wrote the manuscript that is the main part of the story?

Comment: @M.A.Golding the narrator. Zamacona is dead long ago since the narrator found the manuscript

Comment: [Related question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/233117/what-is-meant-by-the-final-sentence-in-the-mound-by-h-p-lovecraft-and-zealia)